# how to make multi-threads use 100% CPU, say 4 threads kill 4 cores to 100%

Tags: multithreading, unix, posix, scheduling

My question: how to make multi-threads use 100% CPU (at least 80%), say let 4 threads use 4 cores to 100%?

The whole story:
I wrote some posix multi-threads code. When run it on a multi-core (up to 16) cluster server, although the wall time decrease with using more cores, the overall computation time ( the sum of time spent on the part of code ~without~ any synchronization ). I guess it is because some cores did not dedicate to running my thread. My guess is confirmed when run the code on my laptop.

I tried to assign affinity with pthread_setaffinity_np 
    and to set priority pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attributes_, SCHED_FIFO);
                        pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attributes_, &p);

which doesn't help.

Comment: Are your threads CPU bound?

Comment: Hi, Christian I think it is CPU bound. It always kills a single CPU. very few I/O.

Comment: Maybe your threads are all contending for the same memory regions, forcing the CPU caches to be cold most of the time?

Comment: You cannot take advantage of 16 processor cores with 4 threads, you'll only use 4 of them.  Trying to scale that up tends to produce bugs instead of faster code.

Comment: Hi Celada, how to detect the memory problem you mentioned?

Comment: Hi Hans, I do know that. My code was for dynamic load balancing. The total amount of computation work is fixed. It's free to add thread from 1 to 16.

Comment: @YaoZhao use the @ sign in front of user names to have their attention. Regarding thread contention: they will access the same memory regions if they read/write to the same variables. It is also possible that they access different data which get mapped to the same areas in cache (the same cache lines).

Comment: @didierc thank you for your remind. The computation part does not including read/write to the same variables. So I guess it might be the false sharing issue. Could you give me more advice on how to deal with the cache problem?

Comment: @Celada Even if this were true, every thread would still be reported by the OS as taking 100% CPU time each.  YaoZhao, if you get a total CPU time that is less than (100*N)% with N threads, it means that some of them are blocked in a system call (lock contention?).

Comment: @ArminRigo you're absolutely right. Scratch that theory I guess :-(